# How to convert MultipartFileStreamProvider type to HttpPostedFileBase in webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

i am sending a multipartrequest from android client to web api it works am receiving file and value but i need to convert the filetype to HttpPostedFileBase i have researched a lot but none of them has got answer for this is it possible to do so let me post the code what i have tried so far:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/api/inoteupload")]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> UploadFiles()
{
    int iUploadedCnt = 0;
    try
    {

        // DEFINE THE PATH WHERE WE WANT TO SAVE THE FILES.
        string sPath = @"D:\sfuploads";
        sPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/");
         MultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(sPath);
        MultipartFileStreamProvider multipartFileStreamProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
        String userid=streamProvider.FormData["userid"];
        String date = streamProvider.FormData["date"];
        String type = streamProvider.FormData["type"];
         HttpPostedFileBase hpf = null;
         UploadManager objUploadManager = new UploadManager(UploadTarget.INote, UploadFolder.Original);
        UploadFileInfo objUploadFileInfo = objUploadManager.Upload(hpf);
        iUploadedCnt = 1;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
        iUploadedCnt = 0;
    }

    // RETURN A MESSAGE (OPTIONAL).
    if (iUploadedCnt > 0)
    {
        return iUploadedCnt + " Files Uploaded Successfully";
    }
    else {
        return "Upload Failed";
    }
}
```

in multipartFileStreamProvider  am getting values and file how can i convert that file type to httppostedfilebase.  This may be dumb question but as a new to webapi and c# am struggling with this can someone help me? Thanks in advance!!